# Adobe Javascript Vs. Plugin

Tags: javascript, pdf, plugins, adobe, acrobat-sdk

Iam nnew to Adobe SDK. we have a requirement to call a DLL from acrobat reader and the DLL will upload the document into a repository. this must happen at click of a menu item
I was able to create the menu item using Javascript.

Will it be possible for me to call an external DLL from Javascript in Adobe or do i have to use Adobe Plugin devlopment option

Answer (score 1):

Essentially no. You may play around a bit with `launchURL()` and see if you can get to the DLL (good luck on that). Keep in mind that Acrobat JavaScript is quite well sandboxed, however.

With a plug-in, you will have to carefully read the terms and conditions of the Acrobat SDK, and the licensing for use in Reader.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.